# trying to open a file in its own program and wait until it closes

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, registry

as a part of a python project i'm writing i need to open a file (could be all sorts of types) in its own program according to the registry (i need it to work on windows only) and wait until the program is closed so i can check if the file was changed (or edited in the program).

i read a lot of other questions about this subject, yet i can find the solution.

i tried using subproccess.Popen, call or check_all as well as os.startfile and psutil for checking the pid of the procces.

**EDIT**: all the files are located in the same folder with the script that opens them. i can open the files yet i cant get it to wait until it closes. it will wait only when the program is notepad.exe

**EDIT 2**: so far i used this code:

```
doc = subprocess.Popen(["start", "/WAIT", file_path], shell=True)
doc.wait()
```

this code opens any file i ask it to but the doc.wait() will wait only when notepad.exe is the opened program. for example, i tried opening a .docx file with microsoft word and it opened but didnt wait for me to close the document.
i cant run it without shell=True because when i do it throws a "can find file" error.

thanks for any answers,
dor

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question, as well as the output or errors you have so far.

Comment: i updated the question with the current code and extra details.

Comment: This is due to how `start` and Word works together. You'll see the exact same behavior if you run `start /WAIT winword.exe` on the command line. If Word is already running, it will just open a new document and then carry on. However, if Word is not yet started, your program will start a new process and then hang until Word is exited. This behavior, however, is dangerous to rely on, since you never know what Word documents are already opened.

Comment: i get it, thanks! yet is there a solution for all sorts of file including .docx? i will give some more data, my code need to open the file for edit and take the updated fie and save it in another computer using tcp socket. so far i thought it was best to hang the script until the editing is done and than continue. i also tried checking the "last modified" value of the file but the problem is that i dont know when the file is closed and i can move on with my code.